# Prevent MailItem.Reply from opening Inspector window in Outlook 2016

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I am building a addin for Outlookto add custom signature in outlook email, when the user click on "Reply" button.
As soon as user click on reply button in explorer, a new inspector opens and i close the inspector with code (which s#cks). There may be a way to totally disable the reply inspector from opening.

```
    private Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane CustomTaskPane;
    UserDetail usr = null;
    Outlook.Explorer currentExplorer = null;
    Outlook.MailItem mailItem;
    private Inspector replyInspector;

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        currentExplorer = this.Application.ActiveExplorer();
        currentExplorer.SelectionChange +=
                            new Outlook.ExplorerEvents_10_SelectionChangeEventHandler(CurrentExplorer_Event);
    }
    private void CurrentExplorer_Event()
    {
        if (this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection.Count == 1
        && this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1] is Outlook.MailItem)
        {
            if (mailItem != null)
            {
                // when the reply button is clicked
                ((Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)mailItem).Reply -= new Outlook.ItemEvents_10_ReplyEventHandler(MailItem_Reply);

                // When an item is selected
                Outlook.Selection mySelection = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection;
                Outlook.MailItem mailitem = null;
                foreach (Object obj in mySelection)
                {
                    if (obj is Outlook.MailItem)
                    {
                        mailitem = (Outlook.MailItem)obj;
                        if (mailitem != null)
                        {
                            if (mailitem.Sent)
                            {

                            else
                            {
                                // Compose
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            mailItem = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1];
            ((Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)mailItem).Reply += new
             Outlook.ItemEvents_10_ReplyEventHandler(MailItem_Reply);
            // Close Inspector
            replyInspector.Close(OlInspectorClose.olDiscard);
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }

    void MailItem_Reply(Object response, ref bool cancel)
    {
        try
        {
            MailItem mitem = (Outlook.MailItem)response;
            replyInspector = (mitem).GetInspector;
            replyInspector.Activate();
            (mitem).HTMLBody = tempSignature + ((Outlook.MailItem)response).HTMLBody;
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, why would you want to close the inspector if you are opening it anyway? Why not insert the signature when the inspector is opened?

Secondly, you cannot concatenate two HTML strings and expect the resulting string to be valid HTML, The two needs to be merged. Or, better yet, use Word Object Model (`Word.Document` is returned from `Inspector.WordEditor`) to insert any text anywhere in the message body.

Comment: Is there any other way to add Signature in Reply Email without opening the inspector?

Comment: Sure, you can insert the signature programmatically - it is just a file with possible external files (images). Or you can use Redemption - it exposes RDOSignature.ApplyTo method.

Comment: Actually, i dont want to open inspector. I want that the reply email can only be edited in explorer. Is there any way to write an reply without  opening inspector . I will be thankful to you, if you could share any tutorial page .

Comment: But that is how Outlook implements the replies, does it not? It defaults to the inline reply, and displays a pop up only if you click "Pop Up" button.

Comment: Actually, my code opens 2 windows for reply. One in popup and other one is in the main explorer

Comment: Of course, because you call Inspector.Activate.Why would you need that?

Comment: Thanks dude, I solved the problem by changing " MailItem mitem = (Outlook.MailItem)response" to "MailItem mitem = (Outlook.MailItem)this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1];"

Comment: Now the problem is that the tempsignature string appear in the recieved message, as soon as i click on reply button.

Comment: Yes, you want the response object passed to your event handler, not the selected item.

Comment: i am unable to add signature string in the reply email now. could you help me with that ?

Comment: when i use "mailItem.Body = tempSignature + ((Outlook.MailItem)response).Body; " now . The tempSignature get added to the recieved message (message recieved) and when i click on the "discard" button, it stays in the recieved message.

Comment: No, i am not getting any error. please check my last message.